# How do you examine objects from psql?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-schema

I want to examine an index (and other objects) from psql.

I created the index with:

```
CREATE INDEX my_index on "my_table" (iso_country_code, type_name, UPPER(name) varchar_pattern_ops);
```

In psql I used the describe command:

```
db=> \d+ my_index
Index "public.my_index"
      Column      |          Type          | Storage  | Description 
------------------+------------------------+----------+-------------
 iso_country_code | character varying(3)   | extended | 
 type_name        | character varying(300) | extended | 
 pg_expression_3  | text                   | extended | 
btree, for table "public.my_table"
```

The expression in the last field of the index says only `pg_expression_3`. Why does the expression not show up in the psql output?

I can retrieve the table schema including the CREATE INDEX statements using pg_dump:

```
pg_dump --table my_table --schema-only my_db
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's clearly pre-9.0 behaviour, take a look into [`E.5. Release 9.0`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/release-9-0.html#AEN100367):

> - Show definitions of index columns in `\d index_name` (Khee Chin)
>
>   The definition is useful for expression indexes.

For previous versions you can still fetch expression manually traversing [system catalogs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/catalogs.html) and using [`pg_get_indexdef(index_oid, column_no, pretty_bool)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE) function, e.g.:

```
=> SELECT oid FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c WHERE c.relname LIKE 'my_index';
  oid  
-------
 25240
(1 row)
=> SELECT attname, attnum FROM pg_attribute a WHERE a.attrelid = '25240';
     attname      | attnum 
------------------+--------
 iso_country_code |      1
 type_name        |      2
 pg_expression_3  |      3
(3 rows)
=> SELECT pg_get_indexdef(25240, 3, true);
 pg_get_indexdef 
-----------------
 upper(name)
(1 row)
```

Comment: That's quite troublesome when using version 8.x.